# How to write WHERE clause in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I write PostgreSQL `WHERE` clause is the condition order have matter?

Imagine the table where `ID` column is indexed and the `name` is not.

Is these **two queries will get same time** to execute?

1. `SELECT * FROM users WHERE state = 0  AND  id = 3;`
2. `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 3  AND  state = 0;`

And despite on these simple queries. Does Postgres do same optimization for complex queries and when it does not?

Please provide prof links when answering.

Thank you.

Comment: the order does not matter - only grouping with parenthesis does. where clause should always be true or false - how can order chnage the result?.. (true AND true)=true, (true and flase)=false, there is no true1 AND true2 - they are interchangeble

Comment: @VaoTsun: The result is not changed. The time to get this result have matter. In first case the index maybe is not used.

Comment: optimyser decides itself (based on statistics) the order of evaluations - you can't hint him your order (at least not this easily)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-WHERE

> where condition is any expression that evaluates to a result of type
>   boolean. Any row that does not satisfy this condition will be
>   eliminated from the output.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-logical.html

> The operators AND and OR are commutative, that is, you can switch the
>   left and right operand without affecting the result

regarding the "conditions evaluating control", there [are some answers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/115759/30035)